# Rasterize a shapefile - Qgis 3.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I got a problem with the rasterization of a shapefile. Basically my aim is to rasterize a shapefile 'Building' by defining boundaries (Output extent from another simple polygon layer) and output raster characteristics as in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHQs4.png):

[image: Rasterize input window]

I'd like to obtain the features of the output raster image from a reference DEM - 'Layer property' >> 'Metadata' as shown in the following picture

[image: Reference DEM characteristics].

(as I would like, later on, to merge the given 'building' raster and a reference DEM)

By the time I run this command, it takes literally 2 secs and the result is a black/White rasterized image with two available values (1.79769e+308 and -1.79769e+308), all the buildings not shown and, probably, not even rasterized ( I furthermore specify I tried many times to change the symbology/style of the output raster to see if something would have appeared but nothing...).